# Code is throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

Can anyone tell me why this code isn't working? It throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
package blok6afvink6;

/**
 * 
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Blok6afvink6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        //1st, use Scanner to readin all sequence names and sequences;
        //create two arrayList to store sequence names and sequences;
        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> sequence = new ArrayList<String>();

        Scanner ScanLine = new Scanner(new FileReader("OverlapGraph.txt"));
        String seq = "";
        while (ScanLine.hasNextLine()) {
            String temp = ScanLine.nextLine();
            if (temp.charAt(0) == '>') {
                sequence.add(seq);
                name.add(temp.substring(1));
                seq = "";
            } else {
                seq += temp;
            }
        }

        ScanLine.close();
        sequence.remove(0);
        sequence.add(seq);

        //naam en seq printen
        int Len = name.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < Len; i++) {
            System.out.println(name.get(i) + ": " + sequence.get(i));
        }
        //3rd, connect all sequences with O3 overlap, put the linked-names into a new string ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> overLaps = linkOverlaps(name, sequence);

        System.out.println("\nPrintout results:");
        for (int i = 0; i < overLaps.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(overLaps.get(i));
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> linkOverlaps(ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<String> sequence) {
        ArrayList<String> overLap = new ArrayList<String>();
        //int size = name.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
            int Len1 = sequence.get(i).length();

            for (int j = 0; j < name.size(); j++) {
                if (i != j && sequence.get(i).substring(Len1 - 3).equals(sequence.get(j).substring(0, 3))) {
                    String linked = name.get(i) + " " + name.get(j);
                    overLap.add(linked);
                }
            }
        }
        return overLap;
    }

}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:492)
    at blok6afvink6.Blok6afvink6.main(Blok6afvink6.java:36)
```

Comment: Because you are trying to remove an element from the `sequence` `ArrayList` that doesn't exist: `sequence.remove(0);`

Comment: How do you know that the ArrayLists will always have items in them?

Comment: You should explain why you think this exception is different than all the other times people got the same exception.

Comment: printout to screen as you process the lines to make sure it is working. Or step though with the debugger. Whatever you find more useful

Answer (score 3):

Line 36 referenced in the exception appears to be:

```
sequence.remove(0);
```

This can only fail with this exception if the list was empty.

So one has to assume that `sequence.add(seq);` is never called.

If that's OK and expected, you could check for empty first:

```
if (!sequence.isEmpty()) {
    sequence.remove(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if(sequence.size() > 0) {
    sequence.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you submitted what you submitted.  Stack Overflow is a knowledge distribution center, not a code writing service.  It would be **a lot** better if OP learned how to fish

Comment: In this case, there was a logic error. We have not a concept error.
Some times, the short answer is the best answer.
Thanks by feedback

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

It would seem that one of your collections has size 0. If so, that would cause this exception because you don't always check to make sure that the collections actually have any items before you try to access them.

Check `sequence` in particular.